# How to configure an USB DDR dance pad for Stepmania?

Tags: hardware, gamepad, 10.04, games

I have Stepmania running and my official Dance Dance Revolution dance pad from DDR Universe 2, but I can't get the former to work with the latter.

`lsusb` says:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12ab:0004 Honey Bee Electronic International Ltd.
```

I tried to look at the relevant Ubuntu documentation for lucid lynx 10.04 LTS, with no luck.

Comment: [Revision history on Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/19567/revisions)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the aforementioned 'relevant Ubuntu documentation'?

Comment: doc.ubuntu-fr.org/joystick

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.stepmania.com/wiki/Configure_Keyboard_and_Dance_Pads#Linux :

For most dance pads, joydev and analog modules are required. Xbox Dance Pads require the xpad module. If they are already compiled with your kernel, try:

```
modprobe joydev
modprobe analog
modprobe xpad (for xbox pads)
```

If not, refer to the manual of your distribution how to get it (you can also download the kernel sources from kernel.org and compile your own kernel yourself).

Then look for some test program, like joystick. Install it with your package manager or compile it yourself.

```
sudo apt-get install joystick
```

And launch :

```
jstest /dev/input/js0
```

You might need to link /dev/input/js0 to /dev/js0 by typing:

```
ln -s /dev/input/js0 /dev/js0
```

*(I modified it a bit, now it's working on Ubuntu)*

I hope this helped you,

Daniel

Comment: Total fail !!! jstest /dev/input/js0 don’t work, so the rest won’t work ...

Comment: @zillion Please read my full answer. `You might need to link /dev/input/js0 to /dev/js0`. You have to link it before you run jstest.

Comment: The link does not work anymore : http://www.stepmania.com/wiki/Configure_Keyboard_and_Dance_Pads#Linux